# JConsole remote connection to JBoss EAP

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, jconsole

I am trying to connect to a remote jboss instance running on a server. I am using the following connection URL

> service:jmx:remoting-jmx://90.214.64.170:9999

When i do this i get the following 2 errors in the console window

[image]

After selecting insecure i am presented with this

[image]

I have, prior to connecting via jconsole also gone to the bin directory of my jboss server and run `./jconsole.sh` which outputs the following to the command line

```
CLASSPATH /usr/bin/java/jdk1.8.0_11/lib/jconsole.jar:/usr/bin/java/jdk1.8.0_11/lib/tools.jar:/var/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/remoting-jmx/main/remoting-jmx-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:/var/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/remoting3/main/jboss-remoting-3.2.18.GA-redhat-1.jar:/var/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logging/main/jboss-logging-3.1.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:/var/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/xnio/main/xnio-api-3.0.7.GA-redhat-1.jar:/var/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/xnio/nio/main/xnio-nio-3.0.7.GA-redhat-1.jar:/var/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/sasl/main/jboss-sasl-1.0.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:/var/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/marshalling/main/jboss-marshalling-1.4.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:/var/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/marshalling/river/main/jboss-marshalling-river-1.4.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:/var/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/cli/main/jboss-as-cli-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:/var/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/staxmapper/main/staxmapper-1.1.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:/var/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/protocol/main/jboss-as-protocol-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:/var/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/dmr/main/jboss-dmr-1.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:/var/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/controller-client/main/jboss-as-controller-client-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:/var/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/threads/main/jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar
```

I am not sure what else i can try (having also opened port 9999) to get this to work, does anyone have any advice or hints that might help resolve this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Having modified my standalone.conf file to this

```
#
# Specify options to pass to the Java VM.
#
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
else
   echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
fi
```

I am still unable to connect - with the same errors as above

Comment: Have you set the appropriate JVM arguments in JBoss to allow it to connect?

Comment: I have not - which arguments are these?

Comment: There's 4 that I can think of: `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote`, `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=[some port number]`, `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=[true or false]`, and `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=[true or false]`. These need to be included in your JAVA_OPTS, with their values set appropriately.

Comment: ahhh perfect thanked - could you give me a hint what to provide for the first option? the other 3  are self explanitory :)

Comment: There is no value for the first one, it's good as is

Comment: You can start JConsole with a `-debug` argument, which might cause it to spit out some more detailed information about why the connection is failing. [This Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/troubleshooting_connection_problems_in_jconsole) has some other troubleshooting steps you could follow.

Comment: Which version of JBoss you are using ?

Comment: JBoss EAP 6.2 I believe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the answer - well at least a solution.

Having read through the new JBOSS release notes [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/pdf/6.3.0_Release_Notes/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform-6.3-6.3.0_Release_Notes-en-US.pdf)for EAP 6.3 I found the following;

> Restored ServiceMBean Helper Classes The org.jboss.as.system-jmx
>   module has been introduced to restore helper classes available in
>   earlier versions of JBoss EAP that assist users in creating MBeans.

What we did was deploy a new standalone instance - clean install of 6.3 and then followed this guide;

https://planet.jboss.org/post/jmx_connections_to_jboss_as

We needed no optional parameters to be added, no modifications to standalone.sh and no modifications for standalone.xml.

I see someone has 5 up votes for an incorrect answer - is this just so the bounty is awarded?!

Comment: Ahh, been struggling with this issue for the past few days too. Just upgraded my install to 6.3 and followed the guide you posted. JConsole appears to be working fine now! Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Follow the instructions mentioned below to enable remote JMX monitoring in JBoss

**JBoss 4.2.3.GA**

Modify run.conf file available in bin directory of JBoss and add below lines-

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<PORT>"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl"
```

**JBoss 5.1.0.GA**

JMX port cannot be configured in JBoss 5.1 due to an existing bug (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-6185) in JBoss which has been fixed in JBoss 6.0 version.

**JBoss 6.1.0.Final**

Modify run.conf file available in bin directory of JBoss and add below lines-

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
JAVA_ARGS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.logging.Logger.pluginClass=org.jboss.logging.logmanager.LoggerPluginImpl"
JBOSS_CLASSPATH="../lib/jboss-logmanager.jar"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<PORT>"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<IP_ADDRESS>"
```

**JBoss 7.1.1.Final**

Modify standalone.conf file available in bin directory of JBoss and add below lines-

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<PORT>"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<IP_ADDRESS>"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/p:../modules/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar  -Xbootclasspath/p:../modules/org/jboss/logmanager/log4j/main/jboss-logmanager-log4j-1.0.0.GA.jar -Xbootclasspath/p:../modules/org/apache/log4j/main/log4j-1.2.16.jar"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.logmanager"
```

NOTE: Modify  and  according to your requirements.

**Reference:**

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossMBeansInJConsole

http://abh1sh3k.blogspot.in/2013/12/jmx-configuration-in-different-versions.html

Comment: do i need these as well as the others in my original post or just these?

Comment: if i add a combination of both i get the following error `Exception thrown by the agent : javax.management.JMRuntimeException: Failed to load MBeanServerBuilder class org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl`

Comment: Add these with other params. Did you added your ip address instead of <host ip> ?

Comment: yes - added my ip address in place of <host ip> - i added my local host address (the ip on the internal network 192.168.0.value) opposed to the external ip

Comment: I also got that exception. But after adding this params worked. For @ashokramcse also working i think. But i am using JBoss 4.0.

Comment: none of the above applies to EAP 6.2 as 1) the MBeanServerBuilderImpl is not packaged any more and 2) these are all settings for non eap jboss

Answer (score 5):

Ok... This was really an issue for me and is important for you to know that if you jave JConsole and JBoss on different machines, **the JConsole that comes with Java DOES NOT WORK**... You have to download a copy of JBoss on the machine you have JConsole and on the bin folder look for the *jconsole.bat* file.

I took it from here: http://www.java-redefined.com/2014/02/jboss-7-with-jconsole.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe for remote connections you have to create an Application Realm user (Using add-user.sh. I answered yes to the question as to whether this would be used for remote server connections or EJB remoting user, though I'm unsure that was strictly necessary).

Then use those credentials to connect with jconsole.

My experience with this also is isolated to remote connections to EAP 6.2.4 running in domain mode. I can only hope remote connections to a standalone server would be the same. It's unclear which you're using here.

I also changed it so I could use port 4447 by issuing this command in the CLI:
/profile=ha/subsystem=jmx/remoting-connector=jmx:add(use-management-endpoint=false)

And it doesn't apply to your issue as it appears you're using JDK 8, but I believe JDK 7 or higher is required (for jconsole).

Hope something here helps!

Answer (score 0):

**JBoss 6.2.0 EAP**

To use JConsole with JBoss 6.2 EAP you must start it adding some JARs to the classpath.

In the directory `/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/client` there is a README file that says:

TO RUN JCONSOLE:

```
jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=<PATH TO jconsole.jar>;<PATH TO tools.jar>;<PATH TO jboss-cli-client.jar>
```

Answer (score 0):

For version 6.1, Make sure you have added the correct portoffset to your default portnumber, 9999 is default, so remote process should work with:

```
service:jmx:remoting-jmx://90.214.64.170:(offsetnumber+9999)
```

Apparently, this got resolved in version 6.2